# Device to make continuous high-resolution photos?

Tags: dslr, resolution, camera-recommendation

I have a problem — I want to make a photo of a surface with high-resolution (>20 Megapixels) every second. If I will use a DSLR camera a shutter will die very quickly.

If I will use a videoflow — there are no one camera I inspected that can write video more than (1920×1080), it's not enough to cover the surface with resolution required.

1 - Is it only software restriction in DSLR cameras that can make a photos with high resolution to form videoflow only (1920×1080)?  Is it possible to hack the camera to 
get videoflow at high resolution?

2 - Are there video cameras that can take photos in high-resolution?

3 - Are there hand-made solutions like [this](https://www.naturalpoint.com/optitrack/products/v120-slim/), but with high-resolution matrix (>20 Mp)? I will mount camera firmly on predetermined distance, so all camera features such autofocus aren't necessary, I need only videoflow or photos in high resolution.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's really a photography question; is this for scientific data acquisition?

Comment: @mattdm the question is relevant to timelapse photography now 4K is gaining traction...

Comment: One way to help getting the higher resolution is developing a series of super-resolution images.  So if your original camera only gives you half the resolution, you can use this technique.  I've done it to reduce noise on a series of time lapse images, but you can use it to 'up scale'.  The trick is to pick a shutter speed and frame rate that can be merged to still show the change you want.  In your case, frames 1 to 4 become super-resolution frame 1,then frames 2 to 5 become SR frame 2, frames 3 to 6 become SR frame 3 and so forth ...

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a camera with an electronic shutter.  There are sensors that can capture image data without need of a mechanical shutter.  Basically the photosites just need to either a) be able to copy off data at the same time, such as a CCD sensor, b) be able to read the data fast enough that not a substantial amount of additional information accumulates or c) be able to electronically cut-off building a charge on the sensor itself.

If you find a DSLR or Mirrorless camera with an electronic shutter capability, you could simply use that to take your images without having any need of using a mechanical shutter that would be prone to failure.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an IP camera would work.  I'm a couple years out of an aerial imaging business where we were using IP cams to capture nadir images for research and such.

A quick search turned this 29mp camera up (2 images per second, and it supports EF lenses) - http://avigilon.com/products/video-surveillance/cameras/hd-pro-cameras/hd-pro/29-mp-jpeg2000-hd-pro-camera/.

Another site with an EF 100-400 zoom attached to the camera: http://bienbac.net/archives/1011.

Other IP cams and lens options exist, I'm just not current as to what's on the market.